# how to make an Ajax request to a URL and append the url with query string in order to run the url program

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get information from a form without using a submit button. First I need to build a query string and then I need to make an ajax request to a URL that contains a program that will take the information from the forms to calculate the mileage from one city to the other. here is my http file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mileage Calculator</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Mileage Calculator</h1>

    <form>
    Start City<input type="text" id="startCity" name="startCity"></input><br><br>
    Start State<input type="text" id="startState" name="startState"></input><br><br>
    End City<input type="text" id="endCity" name="endCity"></input><br><br>
    End State<input type="text" id="endState" name="endState"></input><br><br>

    <input type="button" onclick="buildQuery()" value="Submit"></input>

    </form>

    <p id="justTry">Let's see if we can change this guy</p>

    <script src="assign12.js"></script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

I am using an onclick event to call a javascript function that collects all the form info and arranges it into a query string. Here is that function "buildQuery()" :

```
function buildQuery() {

    startcity = document.getElementById("startCity").value;
    startstate = document.getElementById("startState").value;
    endcity = document.getElementById("endCity").value;
    endstate = document.getElementById("endState").value;

    var params = {
        startcity,
        startstate,
        endcity,
        endstate
};

var esc = encodeURIComponent;
var query = Object.keys(params)
    .map(k => esc(k) + '=' + esc(params[k]))
    .join('&');


    loadSite(query);
}
```

the buildQuery() function then calls the loadQuery(query) function which makes an ajax request. This is were I am having trouble. the query string must be appended to the URL so it can take the form info and calculate the mileage, but I'm not sure how to get that to happen. here is what I have so far:

```
function loadSite(query) {


    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          appendQuery(this.responseText);
          //document.getElementById("justTry").innerHTML = url;                         
      }
    };
    var url = "/cgi-bin/ercanbracks/mileage/mileageAjaxJSON" + query;

    xhttp.open("POST", "/cgi-bin/ercanbracks/mileage/mileageAjaxJSON", true)
    xhttp.send();
}
```

what is the best way to accomplish this task?
thanks, Megan

Comment: define "best way"

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx I would define it as anyway.. I am desperate at this point!

Comment: Then instead of getting all the inputs by ids, you should use `document.querySelectorAll('form *[name=]')` which would automatically select all the subsequent input that does have a name

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx that sounds like a good idea, would you be willing to provide an example? I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you should not manually select all the inputs with ids. Instead I would recommend selecting the inputs using `querySelectorAll` as below

```
function getFormPayload(formId){
    const payload = {};
    for(const input of document.querySelectorAll(`form#${formId} *[name]`)){
        payload[input.getAttribute('name')] = input.value;
    }
    return payload;
}
```

With the function above you can then iterate through the value and create the query as you initially did.

p/s: Note that some elements like `select` doesn't have value attribute so you would need to wrap the value assign in an if statement. Good luck!

Comment: Make sure you assign the form with a specific id to enable multiple form and supply it as an argument for the above function